# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Typeahead / Tagsinput Completing Twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

Edit:  Added [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aawmp3np/)

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap TagsInput with Bootstrap Typeahead.  My source is a json file, but that is irrelevant, and I've checked with a static source.

[image]

The typeahead and tagsinput are working, however when I press enter, tab, or click on a tag, it creates a duplicate complete.

[image]

That extre 'default' happens whenever I press enter, or complete the typeahead.  If I break the typeahead by separating with comma, or taking focus away from the window, it does not occur.

Here is the input:

```
<input id="itemCategory" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="tagsInput form-control" name="itemCategory">
```

And here is the script:

```
    <script>                        
        $('.tagsInput').tagsinput({
            confirmKeys: [13, 44],
            maxTags: 1,
          typeahead: {                  
            source: function(query) {
              return $.get('listcategories.php');
            }
          }
        });
    </script>
```

I'm sure it's something wonky that won't be reproducable, with my luck, so I'm hoping someone will have some institutional knowledge that they know would cause something like this to happen.

Here is an image of the extra text, in dev. tools:
[image]

I really appreciate any advice or suggestions.  Thank you.

**WORKING CODE**

Thanks to @Girish, the following was what "fixed" this issue.  I believe it to be a bug at this point in time, introduced somewhere in a more recent version of jQuery or the Typeahead.  This code just manually removes the extra element, although hopefully something will come along to prevent it from being placed there in the first place, eliminating the extra code.  For now it works for me.

```
        $('.tagsInput').tagsinput({
            confirmKeys: [13, 44],
            maxTags: 1,
          typeahead: {                  
            source: function(query) {
              return $.get('tags.php');
            }
          }
        });
        $('.tagsInput').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(">input[type=text]",".bootstrap-tagsinput").val("");
            }, 1);
        });
```

Comment: your jsfiddle is not working

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla By not working do you mean not demonstrating my problem or is showing my problem?

Comment: the files included from http://www.kobrien.me/ are facing a `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` error and not being loaded in the fiddle. Try including files from some cdn instead

Comment: Could you recommend a way to host them for jsfiddle where it won't face this issue? My server's certificates are self signed.

Comment: try using https://rawgit.com/ That works on jsfiddle for sure. Just paste the raw js/css files in rawgit.com. Rawgit will spit out cdn.rawgit.com urls that can be included in jsfiddle

Comment: Just what I needed!  Thank you.  Please check https://jsfiddle.net/aawmp3np/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is looking bug, nothing custom code inside function, but selected **tag** is repeated in input field, but you can use alternative solution, `itemAdded`  event to remove selected value from `input` field, see below  sample code.

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
  },
  freeInput: true
});
$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(">input[type=text]",".bootstrap-tagsinput").val("");
    }, 1);
});
```

I have also noticed the input field is generating every tag section so `this` or `event` couldn't be targeted tag input field, due to dynamic generation input field you will also need to delay to select input element from `<selector>`

## DEMO

**UPDATE** : `$.get()` function is return `xhr` object not server response, so you need add `callback` method to get AJAX response, see below sample code.

```
$('.tagsInput').tagsinput({
      confirmKeys: [13, 44],
      maxTags: 1,
      typeahead: {                  
          source: function(query) {
            return $.get('listcategories.php').done(function(data){
              /*if you have add `content-type: application/json` in 
                server response then no need to parse JSON otherwise,
                you will need to parse response into JSON.*/
              return $.parseJSON(data);
            })
          }
      }
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems I can't get this to function with my own dataset, pulled from JSON.

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer, as my bounty was expiring and I think you deserve the points, but I think the issue is not fixed, and may be a bug.  

Thank you for your help, @Girish.

Comment: Works for the adding case but doesn't work for the duplication case (when tag is already exist)

Answer (score 3):

A less verbose solution using `afterSelect` option:

```
$(".tags").tagsinput({
     typeahead: {
        afterSelect: function(val) { this.$element.val(""); },
        source: keywords
     }
});
```

Comment: Shortly after posting this I gave up on tagsinput. Too many issues. Instead I opted for Tagify, a js/scss solution which has a built in dropdown. Much cleaner and very simple.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Tagify! I switched to it after reading your comment, and it was a lot cleaner, simpler, and less buggy. It made my development a lot easier. Thank you!

Comment: much better solution. Also work when select/enter the same value second time.
@Girish solution not work for that case.