# jQuery Typeahead - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I am using the [Bootstrap-3 Typeahead plugin](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) as well as the [Bootstrap Tag Input plugin](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/). I use it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="test" data-provide="typeahead">
```

And the jQuery:

```
$.get('/design/assets/advertisements/countries.json', function(data) {
    $("#name").typeahead({
        source: data
    });
    $('#name').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: data
        }
    });
}, 'json');
```

However, the typeahead and tags works to some point. Whenever I enter some words, i get suggestions, but whenever I've selected a suggestion, whatever I was writing will be added after the tag input.

**Example:** If I write "`Bah`" and select "`Bahamas`", it looks like this: (Where I would believe that it would delete the "Bah")

[image]

I get this error - I don't know if that's the reason:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

The error is called to this file:  `bootstrap3-typeahead.js`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360584/twitter-bootstrap-3-typeahead-tagsinput-completing-twice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've downloaded non-min version of bootstrap-3 typeahead plugin and changed this:

```
displayText: function(item) {
  return item.name || item;
},
```

to this

```
displayText: function(item) {
  if (typeof item == 'undefined') {
    return '';
  }
  return item.name || item;
},
```

It solved the problem.

Actually I don't know whether it's a bootstrap-3 typeahead plugin bug or some kind of it's incompatibility with bootstrap tags input plugin which I use.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following change for Bootstrap 3 - typeahead in line number 312

Old Code:

```
displayText: function (item) {
      return typeof item !== 'undefined' && typeof item.name != 'undefined' && item.name || item;
},
```

Updated Code:

```
displayText: function (item) {
        if(item){
                if(item.name){
                    return item.name;
                }
                return item;
        }
        else{
            return '';
        }
    },
```