# jquery UI, Bootstrap 3, bootstrap-tokenfield not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tokenfield

jquery UI, Bootstrap 3 and [bootstrap-tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) are not working with ajax.

The local source example bellow works:

```
$('.Subject-PreRequisites').tokenfield({

            autocomplete: {
                source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo'],
                delay: 100
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
        });
```

But when I introduce the ajax call like:

```
$('.Subject-PreRequisites').tokenfield({
            autocomplete: {
                source: $.get(getallsubjectsUrl, function(data) {
                        return data;
                    }, 'json'),
                delay: 100
            },
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
        });
```

Than I tough it would be a problem with the timing, so I modified it a bit:

```
var sourceTokens = '';
        $.get(getallsubjectsUrl, function(data) {
            sourceTokens =  data;
        }, 'json')
        .done(function() {
            $('.token-input-dropdown').tokenfield({

                autocomplete: {
                    source: sourceTokens,
                    delay: 100
                },
                showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
            });

            });
```

And even the correct source is assigned, the dropdown is not shown.

Is there any other option for bootstrap 3 to have this same functionality ? 
I saw a possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505760/using-bootstrap-tokenfield-with-bootstrap-3-typeahead), but it's link is broken.
If not, how to fix that ?